# Pasar variable de un formulario a otro en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy tratando de concatenar una variable que obtengo de un formulario para mostrarla en otro, lo hago de la siguiente manera.

*1.Formulario*

```
ClsIntermedia objLibreria = new ClsIntermedia();
                    if (objLibreria.Validar_Usuario(this.txtusuario.Text, this.txtcontrasena.Password.ToString(), out respuesta, out respuesta2)) 
                    {
                        Principal ventana = new Principal();
                        ventana.usuarioini = respuesta;
                        MessageBox.Show("BIENVENIDO: " +respuesta+ " "+"DE: " +respuesta2+"", "SICAP, Agrosan S.A.S", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                        ventana.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(objLibreria.Error, "Error del sistema", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        objLibreria = null;
                        this.txtusuario.Text = "";
                        this.txtcontrasena.Password = "";
                        this.txtusuario.Focus();
                    }
```

Donde la variable **usuarioini** la tengo publica en el segundo formulario, obtengo el dato lo asigno y cuando lo concateno en el segundo formulario, no me muestra el dato.

*2. Formulario*

```
public string usuarioini ="";

            public Principal()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Title = Modelo.Util.Mensajes.MsjInicio + " " + "USUARIO: " + usuarioini + " " + "VERSIÓN: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("version");
            }
```

No se si tenga algo que ver, el echo de que cuanto el segundo formulario se lanza este carga los valores que tenga el constructor, y como la variable toma el valor, y el segundo formulario ya esta cargado, no se si es por eso que no lo puede cargar.

De antemano agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es exactamente el que sospechas. Cuando tu modificas `usuarioini` en `ventana.usuarioini = respuesta;`, ya ha pasado por el constructor del segundo formulario poniendo el valor de `this.Title`.

Tienes una solución muy sencilla. En lugar de usar una variable, utiliza una propiedad, y en el `set` modifica `this.Title`. Algo asi:

```
private string usuarioini="";
public string Usuarioini
{
    get
    {
        return this.usuarioini;
    }
    set
    {
        this.usuarioini=value;
        this.Title= Modelo.Util.Mensajes.MsjInicio + " " + "USUARIO: " + value + " " + "VERSIÓN: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("version");
    }

}
```

Y en el otro formulario, cambia la propiedad:

```
ventana.Usuarioini = respuesta;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, tu aporte me sirvio mucho, tenia la duda de que era por el constructor, de nuevo mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mejor trabaja de esta forma 
Formulario 1

```
prinicipal ventandados = new prinicipal();
        AddOwnedForm(ventandados);
        ventandados.Show();
```

Formulario 2

```
secundario ventanauno = Owner as secundario ;
        ventanauno.usuarini = respuesta;
```

Comment: podrias mirar [answer]? no se entiende nada de esta respuesta